# "initializer element is not constant" error in gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, initializer

I try to compile a C code using make file. I get the following error:

```
/home/dev5/src/ermparselex.c:69: error: initializer element is not constant
/home/dev5/src/ermparselex.c:69: error: (near initialization for âyyinâ)
```

Code snippet along with line numbers:

```
65 int yyleng; extern char yytext[];
 66 int yymorfg;
 67 extern char *yysptr, yysbuf[];
 68 int yytchar;
 69 FILE *yyin = stdin, *yyout = stdout;
 70 extern int yylineno;
 71 struct yysvf {
 72         struct yywork *yystoff;
 73         struct yysvf *yyother;
 74         int *yystops;};
 75 struct yysvf *yyestate;
 76 extern struct yysvf yysvec[], *yybgin;
```

The values of `stdin` and `stdout` are not defined anywhere in this code.
I could not get a proper solution from google. Any idea why this error occurs?

Comment: What are the versions of `lex/flex` and `gcc` you are using?

Comment: gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44), flex version 2.5.4

Comment: Hi Ignacio, thanks for the response. I am not sure what you exactly mean.

Answer (score 5):

In C a global variable can only be initialized with a constant expression or a string literal, and the rules for constant expressions are much stricter than in C++.

`stdin` and `stdout` are pointers referring to global objects, they are not constants (the addresses might not be known until link-time) so you cannot use them to initialize global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're include'ing stdio.h, and remove the braces:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *yyin = stdin, *yyout = stdout;
```

The include defines stdin/stdout.

The braces
'{}' change how the values of 'stdin' and 'stdout' are interpreted by the compiler, don't do that.

Comment: Hi telornix, my code contains #include<stdio.h>. I also tried removing the braces. Still I get the same error.

Comment: then you're missing a ';' (semicolon) or something in a line previous to line 69.  Some more lines above what you've given would be helpful.

Comment: I have modifed the question to include code snippets above and below line no 69

Comment: Evidently it's something about the fact that 'stdin' and 'stdout' aren't REALLY constants.   You'll likely need to initialize the values of yyin and yyout to stdin/stdout somewhere in main() or wherever they're used.  Rewriting that line to read "FILE *yyin,*yyout;" causes everything to compile properly.  Call it a quirk of C.  If you had true constants to put there (like 17 or 0x743, then it would work).